# Not Found Error in Pytesser3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, pytesser

```
import pytesser3
import Image
a = Image.open("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\test.png") 
b = pytesser3.image_to_string(a)
print(b)
```

I tried to make a simple OCR program but whenever I run it I get the following error. I have even uninstalled pytesser3 and reinstalled it but nothing has changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/crossword.py", line 4, in <module>
    b = pytesser3.image_to_string(a)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-    packages\pytesser3\__init__.py", line 30, in image_to_string
call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\pytesser3\__init__.py", line 20, in call_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
```

Here is the test.png: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjbc.png

---

```
import pytesser3
import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytesseract'
a = Image.open("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\test.png")
b = pytesseract.image_to_string(a)
print(b)
```

I did what you said but now I've got a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/crossword.py", line 6, in <module>
b = pytesseract.image_to_string(a)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
config=config)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare the pytesseract path:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-
OCR/tesseract'
```

Answer (score 0):

open "**init**.py" file in pytesser3 module. The path would be like "c:\....\Python\site-packages\pytesser3" or inside "c:\....\Python\Lib\site-packages\pytesser3".

And modify the variable value for "tesseract_exe_name = " to your pytesseract path which would be like "C:\....\Python\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract" or "c:\....\Python\site-packages\pytesseract"

It will resolve the issue.